# Checkboard-like background with editable colors

Tags: html, css, svg, png, background-image

In my web game, I'd like to put a checkboard background. My first thought was to create a **2x2 PNG image** and use `background-size`, which would work just fine.

Then I thought it would be very nice to be able to set the colors in the code. What I did for now, is using a **PNG with black 10% alpha pixels in top-left and bottom-right corner**, like this:

```
body {
    background-color: #d83;
    background-image: url('../images/background-mask.png');
    background-size: 100px;
    background-position: 25px 25px;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

It gives me more control, as I can change the base color easily. The limitation is obvious though - the other color will always be 10% darker. It can't be, for example, completely different color.

Another thought was using an **SVG** with 4 rectangles inside, but it feels a little awkward to go vector here.

**data-uri** will most likely be unreadable, so I won't be able to edit it easily.

I'd like to avoid any **JavaScript tricks** to make it. It would work, but again - feels awkward.

Are there any solutions I could consider? The only thing is I'd like to be able to easily define two colors of the checkboard.

This is an example of my background:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'll write down the best SVG solution I can think of. Decide if you think that is good enough.

Unfortunately, none of the attributes of `<pattern>` are presentation attributes, so you cannot set them by CSS.

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.one {
  fill: #d1853b;
}
.two {
  fill: #f6d5b4;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg>
    <pattern id="checkered" viewBox="0 0 1 1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
             x="25" y="25" width="100" height="100">
      <rect class="one" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" />
      <path class="two" d="M 0.5,0 V 1 H 0 V 0.5 H 1 V 0 Z" />
    </pattern>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:url(#checkered)" />
  </svg>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

youc can do so using only css `background-color` no image would be needed just the [nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) propertie then set the td:hover propertie

or you can do so using div :

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

see:

```css
body {
 background: #abdc28;
 padding: 20px;
}

.chessboard {
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 background: #dd8733;
}
.cell {
    width: 40px; height: 40px;
}
.row{
    display:flex;    
    width: 320px;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid #c77a2e;
    border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;}
.row:nth-child(odd) .cell:nth-child(even), .row:nth-child(even) .cell:nth-child(odd) {
 background: #c77a2e;
}
.cell:hover{
   background: green !important;
}
.cell:active {
    background: #0095ff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="chessboard">
 <div class="row"><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div></div>
 <div class="row"><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div></div>
 <div class="row"><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div></div>
 <div class="row"><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div></div>
 <div class="row"><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div></div>
 <div class="row"><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div></div>
 <div class="row"><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div></div>
 <div class="row"><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div><div class="cell"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't like this idea at all. Using table for the background? Nah. Nice beard though :)

Comment: @RoboRobok well if you don't like tables i've used `div's` and `classes`

Comment: It’s not about tables, it’s about using HTML elements for the background. It’s not the best practice, as they are interactive (kinda). Plus, how many cells should I put there? I would need to either put as many as I assume will be enough for most (trick) or use JavaScript to count (trick). If I wanted to use JavaScript, I could think of better solutions anyway.